# Dictionary mutability issue while adding new key and value to the dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to find the longest increasing subsequence from the python list i'm passing. The final dictionary structure should look something like this:

```
Expected structure
subsequence_dict={ 0:[15], 1:[15,27], 2:[14],3:[15,27,38],4:[14,26],5:[15,27,38,55],6:[15,27,38,46],7:[15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85]}

Output:
{0: [15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85], 1: [15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85], 2: [14, 26, 46], 3: [15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85], 4: [14, 26, 46], 5: [15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85], 6: [14, 26, 46], 7: [15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85], 8: [15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85]}
```

As looking at the key 0 in my output it looks there is some mutability issue.

For every value of i in the main function there should be a new key in the dict which has value as list coming from longest_subsequence function.

```
from copy import deepcopy
def longest_subsequence(dict_elent,subsequence_dict):
    """

    :param dict_elent: Dictionary element to which the longest list last element to be compared
    :param subsequence_dict: 
    :return:  List 
    """
    x=subsequence_dict.values()
    sorted_list = sorted(x, reverse=True)
    flag=False
    for sublist in sorted_list:
        if sublist[-1]<dict_elent:
            sublist.append(dict_elent)
            flag=True
            break
    if flag==True:
        return  sublist
    else:
        return [dict_elent]


def main(d,subsequence_dict):
    for i in range(len(d)):
        if i==0 :
            subsequence_dict[i]=[d[i]]
        else:
            subsequence_dict.update({i: longest_subsequence(d[i],subsequence_dict)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d=[15,27,14,38,26,55,46,65,85]
    subsequence_dict={}
    main(d,subsequence_dict)
    print(subsequence_dict)
```

Comment: "As looking at the 0 index itself it tell there is some mutability issue." <- huh?

Comment: @timgeb, I think what OP means is that the first result should be `[15]`, not `[15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85]`.

Comment: @jpp correct, though i have edited that in my question

Comment: You always refer to the same list of values (`x=subsequence_dict.values()`) and then you update its sublists (appending the data instead of instead creating new lists). That being said, I don't understand your logic - how is `[14]` longer increasing subsequence than `[15,27]` to be ranked after it?

Comment: No i'm not using the same list of value here, if i will be having the keys properly added i will be iterating over the values of the keys to check what is the longest list comparing the tail element with the element being passed from dictionary under the current iteration. It is a dynamic programming problem, the [14] mentioned above in the expected output is one of the posibility of longest increasing subsequence and it is not  the final output . May be you can have a look from here to have a better look: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/longest-increasing-subsequent/problem

Comment: What's the dict you are passing? Is your Expected structure is what you are expecting as output?

Comment: subsequence_dict is the  dict which shoud have all the combinations and yes obviously expected structure is what i'm expecting as output @Anil

Comment: @user7422128 - You are using the same sublists (for the most part) - your `subsequence_dict` does update, but the sublists (the values themselves) never get (re)built, you only keep updating them (`sublist.append(dict_elent)`).

Comment: I checked it again by running the debugger, as soon as i pass through the step sublist.append(dict_elent) the list [15,27] which should have been apended only to key 1 of the dictionary  subsequence_dict also get updated for key 0 that is causing the issue.  Can you please provide me with working code snippet? @zwer